# Deserialize class with generated field value

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have a class like:

```
class Pathology:
    """
    Represents a pathology, which is initialized with a name and description.
    """

    def __init__(self: str, name: str, description: str):
        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.phases = []

    def to_json(self):
        return jsonpickle.encode(self, make_refs=False, unpicklable=False)
```

In this class, I do not ever want a user to pass in a value for `id`, I always wish to generate it upon construction.

When deserializing from JSON, I wish to do something like:

```
    with open('data/test_case_1.json', 'r') as test_case_1_file:
        test_case_1 = test_case_1_file.read()

    # parse file
    obj = jsonpickle.decode(test_case_1)
    assert pathology == Pathology(**obj)
```

However, I run into an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

I suspect this is because the init constructor does not have the field `id` available.

What is the pythonic way to support this behavior?

Comment: Why do you pass `unpicklable=False` to `jsonpickle.encode`? If you don't pass this argument then the complete object will be returned from `jsonpickle.decode` and you won't need to initialise the instance yourself

Comment: Was playing with different settings. I will remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this class, I do not ever want a user to pass in a value for id, I always wish to generated it upon construction.

Based on the above desired result, my recommendation is to define id as a (read-only) `property`. The benefits of defining it as a property is that it won't be treated as an instance attribute, and coincidentally it won't accept a value via the constructor; the main drawback is that it won't show in the class's `__repr__` value (assuming we use the generated one we get from dataclasses) or in the `dataclasses.asdict` helper function.

I've also taken added a few additional changes in the implementation as well (hopefully for the better):

- Re-declare the class as a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which I personally prefer as it reduces a bit of boilerplate code such as an `__init__` constructor, or the need to define an `__eq__` method for example (the latter to check if two class objects are equal via `==`). The dataclasses module also provides a helpful `asdict` function which we can make use of in the serialization process.
- Use built-in JSON (de)serialization via the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. Part of the reason for this decision is I have personally never used the `jsonpickle` module, and I only have a rudimentary understanding of how pickling works in general. I feel that converting class objects to/from JSON is more natural, and likely also performs better in any case.
- Add a `from_json_file` helper method, which we can use to load a new class object from a local file path.

```py
import json
import uuid
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field, fields
from functools import cached_property
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Pathology:
    """
    Represents a pathology, which is initialized with a name and description.
    """
    name: str
    description: str
    phases: List[str] = field(init=False, default_factory=list)

    @cached_property
    def id(self) -> str:
        return str(uuid.uuid4())

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(asdict(self))

    @classmethod
    def from_json_file(cls, file_name: str):

        # A list of only the fields that can be passed in to the constructor.
        # Note: maybe it's worth caching this for repeated runs.
        init_fields = tuple(f.name for f in fields(cls) if f.init)

        if not file_name.endswith('.json'):
            file_name += '.json'

        with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
            test_case_1 = json.load(in_file)

        # parse file
        return cls(**{k: v for k, v in test_case_1.items() if k in init_fields})
```

And here's some quick code I put together, to confirm that everything is as expected:

```py
def main():
    p1 = Pathology('my-name', 'my test description.')
    print('P1:', p1)
    p_id = p1.id
    print('P1 -> id:', p_id)
    assert p1.id == p_id, 'expected id value to be cached'

    print('Serialized JSON:', p1.to_json())

    # Save JSON to file
    with open('my_file.json', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(p1.to_json())

    # De-serialize object from file
    p2 = Pathology.from_json_file('my_file')

    print('P2:', p2)

    # assert both objects are same
    assert p2 == p1

    # IDs should be unique, since it's automatically generated each time (we
    # don't pass in an ID to the constructor or store it in JSON file)
    assert p1.id != p2.id, 'expected IDs to be unique'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Gabe no problem, happy to help. Yes, dataclasses in Python are really cool. Also, I realized I forgot to add the `phases` attribute that you had above, so I just added that in the example.